# How to get a specific information from an XML file?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, cpu-word

Good Day! Im very new to XML and trying to get a specific information from an XML file.
Have found a lot of examples on stackoverflow thou all of those I found didnt work for me.

I have an XML [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRkyk.jpg) I need to access line number 655 and get second Value (1st is 6, 2nd is (translating from Russian) Form 5

How would Xpath work here (if it does) will i have to specify every element and node?

Sample:

```
XMLSource = App.ExecuteScript("_LIB_EXTERNFUNCTION", "ObjectToXMLFile", Nothing, True, Obj, True, True, True, True)
XSL = GL_SUPPORTPATH & "\" & "XSL\documents_decor\NODE_DOCUMENT_TYPE_TOMSK\DRAWING_GOST_FORMS_FORM3_WITHOUTHFORM.xsl" 'App.ExecuteScript("A_SSN_TOBJECT_MODULE_V0", "GetXSLForDecore2", Obj)
    If InStr(XSL, "OnlyBarCode") > 0 Then _
        XSL = App.ExecuteScript(Obj.ObjectDefName, "GetXSLForDecore", Obj)
XSL = Replace(XSL, "_WITHOUTHFORM", "")
XMLDestination = App.ExecuteScript("_LIB_EXTERNFUNCTION", "GetTmpFileName", "xml", Obj)
App.ExecuteScript "_LIB_EXTERNFUNCTION", "XSLTTransform", XMLSource, XSL, Empty, XMLDestination

xmlDoc.Load XMLSource
Dim NodeA As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

For Each NodeA In xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes

   ‘Trying to Count or Display them

Next
```

Mayhaps i need to upload the whole file for this. If so please let me know and i will do so.
Any help or reference would be appreciated

Comment: what tooling are you using to "read" the xml file? depending on that I think that a more specific answer can be given. Also depending on the complexity of the message structure a solution path can be chosen.

Comment: Im getting a file from another program which is stored in XMLSource, i can access it but dunno how to get the information out of it. XMLDestination is a filtered file that was done by a side-company people. It does not have the information i need, so i would like to address the Source.

Comment: I think that you are using visual Basic to achieve this. why don't you load the xml file into a xdocument structure and use linq to go through it. or you could do something like dim xdoc = xdocument.parse(xmlSource). dim elmlist = xdoc.descendants("_formaFormat"); dim valuelist = elmlist.descendants("value").toList(); dim value = valuelist[1].value; making the assumption that there is only one _formaformat element and that the required value element is always the second in the xml tree.